# Sample specific area of hypersphere

Tags: probability, geometry, vectors

## Question

I want to find a set of D dimensional vectors with a minimum distance (similarity) to each other. A lab-mate of mine has shown [how to do this using the Graham-Schmidt process](https://forum.nengo.ai/t/generating-highly-similar-spa-vectors/404/10?u=seanny123), but it doesn't seem to be working for high-dimensional surfaces. On a 3D surface, the matrix M, seems to show the boundary of the valid sampling area. How do I sample this surface specifically? Is it possible to generalize this sampling methodology to higher dimensions?

In other words, I'm trying to find a set of vectors $V$ distributed over a hypersphere such that all pairs possible pairs of $V$ have a dot product larger than a similarity $s$. I think this is analogous to sampling a certain area of the hypersphere that $V$ is being sampled from.

## Visualisation and Code

Here is the visualisation that shows M (in green) surrounding the valid vectors (in blue).

[image]

Here is the code I used to create this visualization. I'm using some weird libraries, but this is just so you understand what I'm doing.

```
import nengo
from nengolib.stats import sphere

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def proj(u, v):
    return u.dot(v.T) / u.dot(u.T) * u

uniform_sphere = nengo.dists.UniformHypersphere(surface=True)

d = 3
similarity = 0.3

M = np.zeros((d, d))       # output matrix
Q = np.zeros((d, d))       # Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of S
S = uniform_sphere.sample(d, d=d)  # some random samples used to form Q

for i in range(d):
    Q[i, :] = S[i, :]
    a = similarity/((i-1)*similarity + 1)
    for j in range(i):
        Q[i, :] -= proj(Q[j, :], S[i, :])
        M[i, :] += a*M[j, :]
    M[i, :] += np.sqrt((1 - i*a*similarity)/Q[i, :].T.dot(Q[i, :]))*Q[i, :]

good = []
bad = []
for p in sphere.sample(200, d=d):
    if np.all(M.dot(p.T) >= similarity):
        good.append(p)
    else:
        bad.append(p)

assert len(good) > 0
good = np.asarray(good)
bad = np.asarray(bad)
assert np.all(good.dot(good.T) >= similarity)

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(*bad.T, s=5, c='red')
ax.scatter(*good.T, s=20, c='blue')
ax.scatter(*M.T, s=50, c='green')
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.view_init(45, 45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: "vectors with a minimum to each other"  A minimum WHAT to each other?

Comment: The code looks like python, and as a non python user who also never used the maths lib in python, this is painful to read. A bit more of explaining about what you're trying to achieve in English or maths assertions would be very welcomed. I am currently trying to go through the link you provided to get those information, but your question would benefit from a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @WillJagy similarity/distance /*facepalm/*

Comment: @N.Bach I added further English assertions. Should I remove the figure and code entirely? I don't totally understand it, so it's hard for me explain it.

Comment: I think the edit is better, but it's a little bit late. Especially now that I went through the other link you provided. The figure actually helped a lot. The code somewhat helped, but just the code alone makes for a very poor question. I spent more time than I'd want to admit trying to figure out what you wanted. For future questions, try to help your reader, because people are often lazy and don't want to go around to find the information they need.

Comment: @N.Bach I'm sorry for making things needlessly hard for you. I'll try to make my questions more clear in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly went through the link you provided, and if I understood properly (honestly, I probably didn't), your current problem would be: "how to sample the blue area" and "why does your code fail to find any good sample in high dimension".

---

About your sampling problem, here are my assumptions.

- I will assume that every vectors lie on some hypersphere, cause that's what it looks like in your figure.
- I will also assume that you are able to somehow compute the $D$ green vectors, where $D$ is your dimension. I think those green vectors are stored in your matrix $M$.
- If my understanding is correct, you fix a threshold $b$ of "similarity". The blue surface has the following property:

  > Let $S$ be any sampling of the blue surface. For any two vectors $v_1,v_2\in S$, then $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle \ge b$.

Assuming all of that, that blue surface corresponds to the conical hull of the green vectors, intersected with the hypersphere. If you prefer, you can take the convex hull of those green vectors, and just project that convex hull along the radii of the hypersphere, onto the hypersphere:

> Denote by $M_1,\ldots,M_D$ the $D$ green vectors.
>   Then, for any vector $v$ in the blue surface, there exists $D$ coefficients
>   $0\le \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_D \le 1$ and $\alpha\ge 0$ such that
>
> - $\sum_{i=1}^D\lambda_i = 1$
> - $\hat v=\sum_{i=1}^D\lambda_iM_i$
> - $v=\alpha\hat v$

Basically $\alpha$ is just there to say you should scale $\hat v$ so that it lies on the hypersphere. If my previous assumption about everyone living on some hypersphere is false, then this whole thing is obviously useless.

If I somehow interpreted your question properly and I'm right, then this allows you to systematically pick a point inside your blue surface. If you're fine with $n$ random samples, you can just sample coefficients
$\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_D$ whichever way you like.

---

Regarding your other problem, about why your sampling fails in higher dimensions, it's a bit difficult to say unless you provide us with
a rough idea of the dimension, and how many samples you used.
But if you went into very high dimensions, then the short answer would be "yes, you're underestimating how small the [blue surface] is in higher dimensions".

Consider the $D$ vectors in $M$, they constitute a basis of $\mathbb R^D$. That basis is in general not orthogonal, so not that "nice" to use. But using that basis, the blue surface can be expressed as the portion of the hypersphere that lies within the positive hyperoctant. And that is a very, very small portion of the surface of the complete hypersphere, because there are a total of $2^D$ hyperoctants. So a ballpark estimate indicates that your blue surface represents $\frac 1{2^D}$-th of the surface of the complete hypersphere.

Of course, all hyperoctants are not of the same "angular" size, but in the figure you provided, it is already among the smallest hyperoctants. Additionally, the higher your similarity threshold $b$, the smaller the hyperoctant will be, so any practical use case for you would yield a small surface.